How is Python `pip install` cache file's ID string calculated?
When I use pip install pillow==10.2.0 to install a Pillow on my machine, the original filename from server is pillow-10.2.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl .

After the download, it is cached in my local disk:

C:\Users\chj\AppData\Local\pip\cache\http-v2\5\d\a\8\5\5da855ed79847734593562113083d79c2634b1696f0d635c02984eb4.body


I'd like to know, how is that ID string(as cache filename) 5da855ed79847734593562113083d79c2634b1696f0d635c02984eb4 calculated?
It is not the SHA224 or SHA256 of the .body file.

sha224(5da855ed79847734593562113083d79c2634b1696f0d635c02984eb4.body)=98dede132d9782d07fd42cf70d1734984f8bfd5c60c6018903053d68
sha256(5da855ed79847734593562113083d79c2634b1696f0d635c02984eb4.body)=154e939c5f0053a383de4fd3d3da48d9427a7e985f58af8e94d0b3c9fcfcf4f9

Then what is it?

Can you post that console output as text instead of an image?
